# HTTP login in mechanize

Tags: python, web, mechanize

I am write a script for automate things for one website. But when i open this website it has a login server which ask for username and password you need to pass that authentication to open the website.
i have that authorization details.
[image: authentication that is needed]

so how to open this wesite with the help of MECHANIZE IN PYTHON

```
import urllib
 import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://ab/cabs");
print response.geturl()
print response.read()
```

but it is giving this error
**httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required**

what should i add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from base64 import b64encode
import mechanize

url = 'http://192.168.3.5/table.js'
username = 'admin'
password = 'password'

# I have had to add a carriage return ('%s:%s\n'), but
# you may not have to.
b64login = b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))

br = mechanize.Browser()

# # I needed to change to Mozilla for mine, but most do not
# br.addheaders= [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

br.addheaders.append( 
  ('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % b64login )
)

br.open(url)
r = br.response()
data = r.read()

print data
```

And perhaps didn't try this could also work:

```
import urllib
 import re
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
response = br.open("http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@ab/cabs");
print response.geturl()
print response.read(
```

)

Comment: hey @kyllopardium, first method worked in my case. thanks man for fast reply. I am also curious about second one but my password also have @. so in that case how to use the second solution..?

Comment: I am not sure this will work, but you can try: response = br.open("http://USERN\@ME:PASSWORD@ab/cabs"); 
Remember to put backslashes "\" before every special character.
But I highly recommend sticking with the first method as it's more generic. (and the base64 will make sure you won't have any problem with any kind of password)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied username and password

```
br.add_password("http://ab/cabs", "username", "pswd")
```